# How to disable VS Code suggestion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, autosuggest

I love using VS Code. But sometimes it's showing me all the suggestion at the same time. Even though I was able to disable `abc` suggestion, but I can't disable the first kind of suggestion in the picture because I can't tell what kind of suggestion is this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the types of completions: [completion types](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions).

Unfortunately, the one you refer to is for `keywords` so you may not want to disable that one.

`Editor > Suggest: Show Keywords`

Comment: How can I make this suggestion not come up on top? and thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.  Snippet suggestions you can move.  Given that it is a keyword suggestion it probably scores high on the ranking system for where it will be shown in the suggestions.